# Can't access BrowserHistory from React component props

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is my router definition:

```
export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
        <Route component={Dashboard} exact path="/dashboard" />
        <Route component={Sites} exact path="/sites" />
        <Route component={RegisterSite} exact path="/register" />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

And the creation of the main App component:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Routes />
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

After this setup I thought all the components registered with the Route component should have browserHistory injected into their props but only Dashboard component has history injected into its props. When I try to access history inside of Sites component for example, I get undefined.

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

From the docs,

> A `<Router>` that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.